# Remains me 3 or I've got 3 left?

Tags: phrase-request

If I had 5 apples and now out of them I have only 3.

What's the natural way to say it, while emphasizing that **remains** only three.

> 1) I have (got) 3 apples **left** now.
>
> 2) **Remains me** only 3 apples now.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 is natural and common.

Number 2 is incorrect for a number of reasons.

First, *remain* is an intransitive verb, so it can't be used with a direct object; it would have to be "remain *to* me."

Second, that sentence has a verb-object-subject structure, which we rarely see in English (actually, I can't think of an example that's not non-standard or out of date, e.g. "Knew it all along, I did" - which might actually be an elided subject, and then an emphatic repetition). So we would need to restructure the sentence: "Three oranges remain to me."

Third, we don't typically use *to* or *to me* with *remain*, we're more likely to say something like, "Only three oranges remain in my possession."

Fourth, while "only three oranges remain in my possession" is grammatical, and idiomatic, it sounds very formal and precise and thus, we might say something like this in a court room ("Of the five documents obtained by the defendant, only three remain in his possession"), but probably wouldn't say something like this about oranges.

Answer (score 1):

> Only 3 apples **remain** (to me).

or one of the various other conjugations of the verb:

> Only 3 apples **are remaining.**
>
> Only 3 applies **have remained.**

Or use the existential "there"

> There **remain** only 3 apples.

You can also use "left", although this is the past participle that functions as an adjective:

> Only 3 apples **are left**.

"Remain" doesn't take an indirect object so you would not say "remain me".  Instead use the preposition "to".

> There remains **to Heracles** only one of the golden apples he stole from the Garden of the Hesperides.

(Edit)  Your first example is fine.  Again, it uses the past participle "left" as an adjective, which is natural.

> I have now 3 apples **left**.

The interrogatives of these would be.

> Do only three apples remain?
>
> Are only three apples remaining?
>
> Have only three apples remained?
>
> Does there remain only three apples?
>
> Are there only three apples left?

Comment: Thank you for the answer (^1+). If you don't mind, I'll ask you more 2 questions: 1) what's about my first choice for your opinion? 2) What's the *interrogative form* for what you suggested as existential? ("There remain only 3 apples.")